# Porque meu somatório não funciona?

Tags: c, array, char

Tenho essa atividade:

> Escreva uma funcao que receba, como entrada, um vetor de n > 0 elementos do tipo Cell e devolva, como saida, a
> soma, dos pesos de todos os elementos do vetor que pertencem a faixas. Por exemplo, para a sequencia “yyzzzya”,
> se os pesos destes elementos sao 10,2,5,4,5,4,3, a sua funcgdo deve devolver o valor 26.

Eu inicio ele com os 7 elementos, coloco os mesmo char na descrição e os int mas quando soma me da o valor de 21;
eis o codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    char car;
    int peso;
} Cell;

void SomaDosPesos (Cell vet[],int tam);

int main(){
    int i,tam,a1;

   do
   {
        printf("\nDigite a quantidades de elementos que ira inserir, tem de ser maior que Zero! :"); 
        scanf("%d", &tam);
   } while (tam < 0);
   
    Cell  vet[tam];

    for(i = 0 ; i < tam; i++){
        
        printf("\nDigite um caractere:");
        scanf("%s",&vet[i].car);
        

        printf("\nDigite o peso deste caracter:");
        scanf("%d", & vet[i].peso);

    }
    SomaDosPesos(vet,tam);
    
}

void SomaDosPesos (Cell vet[],int tam){
    int i,aux = 0;
   
    for(i= 0; i < tam ; i++){
        printf("\nFuncao:%c,%d",vet[i].car,vet[i].peso);
    }
    if(vet[0].car  ==  vet[1].car){
           aux += vet[0].peso;
        }
    for(i= 0; i < tam ; i++){
        
        if(vet[i].car  ==  vet[i+1].car){
           aux += vet[i+1].peso;
        }
    }
    printf("\nFuncao peso: %d",aux);
}
```

Comment: A sua função de soma está procurando os caracteres que têm um igual na sua direita (`i + 1`), então ela ignora os _últimos_ caracteres de cada faixa, porque eles só tem um caractere igual à esquerda! Você pode consertar isso colocando um else if no lugar certo.

Comment: onde eu coloco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido:

```
for(i= 0; i < tam ; i++){
        if(vet[i].car  ==  vet[i+1].car){
           aux += vet[i].peso;
           
        }else if (vet[i].car  ==  vet[i-1].car){
            aux += vet[i].peso;
        }
    }
```